# Hide/Show image after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

So I need to have an image alternatively appear and disappear every 2 seconds, I've been trying using javascript and I've gotten stuck, I feel like it's something so simple but i can't work it out, any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="Show()">
<div align="center">
<img id="image" src="image1.png" height="200" width="200">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var Cntr=1

function Hide()
{
    Cntr++;
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility="hidden";
    if (Cntr==2){
        setTimeout("Hide", 2000);
    }
}

function Show() 
{
    Cntr--;
    document.getElementbyId("image").style.visibility="visible";
    if (Cntr==1) {
        setTimeout("Show", 2000);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's either `setTimeout(Hide, 2000)` or `setTimeout("Hide()", 2000)`, preferably the former.

Comment: Even with that fix the logic is off; the first call to `Show()` on page load sets `Cntr` to 0. You don't actually need the variable at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use callback functions in your `setInterval`.

I changed your JavaScript to this:

```
var isHidden = false;

setInterval(function(){
    var el = document.getElementById("image");
    el.style.visibility = isHidden ? "visible" : "hidden";

    // toggle hidden property
    isHidden = !isHidden;
}, 2000);
```

here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9q3EA/) as well.

Comment: thank you, finally got it working with your adjustment

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

1. As  Juhana mentioned, you're using `setTimeout` wrong.
2. `Hide()` isn't being called anywhere.

Here's what you can do:

#### JavaScript

```
// Store the status of the image. Initially it is 'visible'.
var isVisible = "visible";


function blink() {
    // Toggle the position.
    if(isVisible == "visible") isVisible = "hidden";
    else                       isVisible = "visible";

    // Update it.
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = isVisible;

    // Repeat the process every 2 seconds.
    setTimeout(blink, 2000);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<body onload="blink()">...</body>
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk5aT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

in you setTimeout()s swap show and hide. Also, remove var Cntr. wont need it

```
function Hide()
{

document.getElementById("image").style.visibility="hidden";

setTimeout("Show()", 2000);

}

function Show() 
{

document.getElementbyId("image").style.visibility="visible";

setTimeout("Hide()", 2000);


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

`$(function($) {
    setInterval(function() { 
    if($('#image').is(':visible'))
        $('#image').hide();
    else
        $('#image').show();
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a jQuery solution. There is not `jQuery` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery instead of raw JS, it is more clean and simple. Use Delay and FadeTo functions with recursion and you are done with one simple function. Call this on page load.

```
function Flicker(){
    $("#MyImage").delay(1500).fadeTo(300,0).delay(1500).fadeTo(300,1, Flicker);
}
```

Where: #MyImage is ID of image.

You can see this working @ http://jsfiddle.net/BM3qK/1/

Hope this helps.